# How is the following an equivalent proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I am taking a discrete mathematics course and one of the questions asks to develop an English translation of a proposition.

The proposition has the following structure [*Question 9 part H is where I am having issues*]:

[Here is an image of the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSRYX.png)

I posted the question on the course's Piazza page and a student answered this:

```
¬p∧(p∨¬q) {My original proposition}
≡
(¬p∧p)∨(¬p∧¬q)
```

Then saying:

```
(¬p∧p)∨(¬p∧¬q)
=
(p∨¬q) {The proposition that the student claims is == my original proposition.}
```

Obviously **(p∨¬q)** would be simpler to put in words than **¬p∧(p∨¬q)**. Finding an English statement for **¬p∧(p∨¬q)** would be difficult as compared to **(p∨¬q)**.

Is this true? And if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Swimming at the North Shire is **not** allowed [$\lnot p$] **and** (either Swimming at the North Shire is allowed **or** Sharks have **not** been spotted near the shore [$p \lor \lnot q$])

is quite "impossible" as an English (or other natural language) sentence.

Thus, *if* tautological transformations (truth equivalence) are allowed, it is correct that (by [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)):

> $\lnot p \land (p \lor \lnot q)$

is equivalent to :

> $(\lnot p \land p) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$.

Now (see : [Table of Logical Equivalences](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf)) :

> $\lnot p \land p \equiv FALSE$

and :

> $FALSE \lor \alpha \equiv \alpha$.

Thus, the complete formula is equivalent to :

> > $\lnot p \land \lnot q$.